# Setting dimensions of a programmatically created Image before drawing it on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I create an Image object in JavaScript for the purposes of drawing it on a canvas. I set the width and height properties of the image, then draw it on a canvas. The image is drawn at is natural dimensions, not the dimensions that I set.

```
// Assume image is a loaded image object, and ctx is a canvas' 2D context.

image.width=image.width/2;
image.height=image.height/2;
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0); // Draws the image at its original dimensions, not half-size.
```

The only way I know of to draw the image at a different size is to set the width and height explicitly as part of the `drawImage` function, like so:

```
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,image.width/2,image.height/2);
```

Here's a JSFiddle demo of the two methods in action to better illustrate what I'm describing: http://jsfiddle.net/do3gg1cy/.

For my use case I'd like to be able to resize the Image object itself and have it drawn at this size on the canvas (i.e. the first method), rather than having to set the dimensions during the `drawImage` operation.

Am I setting the width and height properties incorrectly, or does anyone know of another way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage), if "dw" & "dh" are omitted, the `drawImage` method establishes the source image dimension from the image's ***intrinsic*** width & height in ***image pixels***. Modifying the `width` & `height` properties doesn't change these intrinsic values.

Comment: You could add that settings those dw and dh to image.width and image.height would solve OP issue

Comment: @Amit thanks for the answer, that pretty much clears up my question. @Kaiido you're right, if I set the `width` and `height` properties of the image then call `ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,image.width,image.height)` that effectively achieves what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Kaiido - has the OP demonstrated in the fiddle, that dosen't work

Comment: @Kaiido Yeah, it does if you reuse the values in the `drawImage` call, but you could put whatever variable, calculation or static value in there to get the same result. The fact that the image object width & height properties are used is not part of the solution here.

Comment: Of course it is, you change these properties to any value and you just reuse it when calling `drawImage`, I don't see your point here...

Comment: The point is that without specifing dw & dh values in `drawImage`, you'd get the original size of the image. If you do specify values, it doesn't matter where they come from, and the fact that you suggest to use `image.width` & `image.height` is not a key factor. In fact you could set these properties to whatever value you want, and it would make no difference at all - [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/do3gg1cy/2/)

Comment: :-) I know how to use `drawImage`, thank you. Op was requesting to be able to change drawnImage width and height properties and then draw at the new size ==> use the newly set `drawnImage.width` and `drawnImage.height` properties